# How to disaply any URL content in model popup?

Tags: magento2

I want to display one URL output in the model popup.

Let's say https://www.demo.com/xyz/xyz/xyz.html I want to display this URL result in [Modal widget.](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_modal.html)

Any one have any idea how we can do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution you can try this

```
var options = {
            type: 'popup',
            responsive: true,
            title: 'Main title',
            buttons: [{
                text: $.mage.__('Ok'),
                class: '',
                click: function () {
                    this.closeModal();
                }
            }]
        };
        var popup = modal(options, $('#modal'));
        $('#modal div.modal-body-content').html('');
        $('#modal div.modal-body-content').load($(this).attr('data-url'))
        $('#modal').modal('openModal');
```

Your solution is this line

```
$('#modal div.modal-body-content').load($(this).attr('data-url'))
```

If you find Right please mark it correct.